# Google Cloud Function Outbound Request Timeouts for Large Job

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I have a cloud function that is essentially acting as a cron task. The function is triggered by a cloud event (typically once per day), and then processes records in a database by pinging a third party API for each record and saving the results to our DB.

The issue I'm running into is that, for larger jobs, at some point the API requests start timing out consistently. Additionally, other requests to other APIs begin to timeout as well, which leads me to believe that there is some throttling of outbound requests in the cloud function itself, but I can't find any docs mentioning this.

Any insight here would be appreciated!

Explicitly what I've observed:

- Logs send API requests successfully
- After some point in time, the only logs that appear are errors indicating a timeout occurred
- The final logs indicate that the cloud function also timed out while trying to hit Redis to release a lock

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Hi Robert, I can work on creating an example but it may take some time. The code I'm using is dependent on integrations with Twilio. as well as 2 separate DB providers, but requests to each of these services all start timing out at around the same time, which makes me think the issue has to do with Cloud Functions